# Why browsers display the prototype property different?

Tags: javascript

I habe the following script:

```
var Person = function (name) {
this.name = name;
};

var person = new Person('James');
console.log(person.name);

var anotherPerson = new Person('Kate');
console.log(anotherPerson.name);

console.log(Person.prototype);
```

and console in Chrome shows me the following:

```
James
Kate
Person {}
```

while Mozilla's console shows

```
James
Kate
Object {}
```

I think that the last variant is correct. So the question why Chrome shows this? I have read that different browsers implement the ____proto____ property differently, but whats wrong in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: The only way to objectively answer the question of why Chrome's console shows `Person` and Firefox's shows `Object` would be if there were code comments or documentation somewhere that could be cited giving the reasoning. I doubt there is. They just made different choices about what to output. Looks like Chrome outputs the name of the object's `constructor` property, and Firefox outputs the text "Object". Neither is wrong. Chrome's might be marginally more helpful (or slightly misleading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log()` is not a standard.  Each browser has its own implementation of what it wants to display.  In your case, Chrome has gone an extra step to notice that it can show you more information than just the plain Javascript type of the object and Firefox did not do that extra work.

If you're looking for some rational reason why either one is doing what it's doing, I doubt you're going to find one.  It's just a difference in implementation.   Neither is wrong.  One is attempting to show you a bit more information.  The two implementations just made a different choice.

Comment: Chrome doesn't even allow me to expand the Person{} constructor to see it's prototype. FF allows to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Firefox (and sometimes Chrome) to show the name of the constructor then don't set Person to an anonymous (unnamed) function. The following will show Person:

```
var Person = function Person(name) {//named function
  this.name = name;
};
console.log(Person.prototype);
```

Why browsers show console.log different things is already answered (implementation is up to the browser). Chrome will show an empty object because that is what it is. If the object has too many properties to show in one line you can also expand it in the console (try `console.log(Array.prototype)`).